# ASP.NET ExecutionTimeout no effect on IIS-hosted WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, wcf-4, asp.net-4.6

I guessed that the ASP.NET ExecutionTimeout would have an effect on my IIS-hosted WCF service, however, it does not.

Is there some magic going on in WCF which disables the ExecutionTimeout?

Comment: Why you think ExecutionTimeout has no effect?

Comment: @Adil: I tried to explicitly reach it via a `Thread.Sleep()` in my service, however, after 5 minutes the service call finished without hitting the timeout of 110 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that since .NET 3.0 SP1 WCF disables ASP.NET's `ExecutionTimeout` by setting the timeout to an infinite value. Therefore, only WCF-specific timeouts apply.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, ASP.NET and WCF are handled by different handlers. Being that ASP.NET and WCF are handled differently and the fact that the executionTimeout is within the child elements of system.web (ASP.NET) and not system.serviceModel (WCF) is probably why it has no effect on WCF calls. It problably has no effect on anything that is not handled by the ASP.NET handlers (e.g.: Static files).